# Sonata Admin - adding help message in filters

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I want to add a help message in the filters form.

I'm able to do it in the edition form, like this:

```
<?php
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper->add('name', null, array('help'=>'Help Message'));
}
```

but that doesn't work on the filters

```
<?php
public function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('name', null, array('help'=>'Help Message'));
}
```

I've also tried the `sonata_help` option, but it doesn't work..

is there a way to add a help message in the filters form (without making modifications on templates)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want override templates, you can use basic jQuery for add attributes to your filters on load page.
(create a script and add it to assets config)

Exemple :

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('#filter_someproperty_value').attr('help', 'Your help text');
});
```

It's quick and not very clean, but it works and it's simple.